# How can I replace an Observable anonymous inner class by lambda, including a logger, for multiple Couchbase access?

Tags: java, lambda, couchbase, observable

I started to use java 8 some days ago and I want to refactor some method using lambda.

The following method is used to get many documents from Couchbase :

```
public List<JsonDocument> bulkGet(final Collection<Long> ids) {
    return Observable
            .from(ids)
            .flatMap(new Func1<Long, Observable<JsonDocument>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<JsonDocument> call(final Long id) {
                    return bucket().async().get(docId(id)).doOnError(new Action1<Throwable>(){
                        @Override
                        public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                            logger.error("Error while bulk fetching SenderEmailAddress with id [" + docId(id) + "] from Couchbase.");
                        }
                    }).onErrorResumeNext(new Func1<Throwable, Observable<JsonDocument>>(){
                        @Override
                        public Observable<JsonDocument> call(Throwable throwable) {
                            return Observable.empty();
                        }
                    } );
                }
            })
            .toList()
            .toBlocking()
            .single();
}
```

And this is the context :

```
private static final Logger logger =  LoggerFactory.getLogger(SenderNameRepositoryCouchbase.class);

public String docId(Long entityId) {
    return CouchbaseBucketFactory.APPLI_PREFIX + DOC_PREFIX + entityId;
}
```

Now, this is my refactored method with lambdas :

```
public List<JsonDocument> bulkGet(final Collection<Long> ids) {
    return Observable
        .from(ids)
        .flatMap((Long id) -> {
            return bucket().async().get(docId(id))
                .doOnError(
                    (Throwable throwable) -> { logger.error("Error while bulk fetching SenderEmailAddress with id [" + docId(id) + "] from Couchbase."); }
                ).onErrorResumeNext(
                    (Throwable throwable) -> { return Observable.empty(); }
                );
        })
        .toList()
        .toBlocking()
        .single();
}
```

But I'm told by SonarLint I should replace this by a method reference. But it's impossible to use a method reference like Class::method with an argument, isn't it ?

By the way, I should not be allowed to use my logger in a lambda, right ?
How can I do that ?
Is it really possible to refactor this class with lambda like Sonar suggests ?

Comment: You could refactor this big lambda body in a method, and then use a reference to that method. Regarding the logger, why couldn't you use it in the lambda?

Comment: (off topic) `-> { expression; }` can be written more simply `-> expression`.  Also, I believe your `.onErrorResume` doesn't need a lambda: '.onErrorResume(Observable.empty())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method references do match functional types that accept parameters.  The compiler will find a method with the specified name whose parameters and return types are compatible with the functional interface called for.  For example for a static method,

```
 Function<In,Out> op = in -> MyClass.doSomething(in);
```

which takes one parameter, is equivalent to

```
 Function<In,Out> op = MyClass::doSomething;
```

When it sees `MyClass::doSomething`, the compiler will see that it needs a `Function<In,Out>` and look for a static method in `MyClass` called `doSomething` that takes a parameter that can accept an `In`, and a return type that can be assigned to an `Out`.

Comment: By the way, the choice of whether to use a lambda or a method reference is mostly a matter of preference.  When given a choice, always choose the style that is clearest to read and understand.  Sometimes a method reference can hide what is happening, so don't blindly follow SolarLint.  If you can turn that particular check off, I'd do it.